# How to use interface to make API responses type safe/declared? TypeScript

Tags: typescript, validation, jsonschema, contentful

I am using TypeScript and Contentful in the same project and am having issue getting my head around how to map out the API response within an interface in a way that is clean and sensible and dynamic some sort as the API responses from contentful are massive and ugly - and for each different content type they could be different.

So these are my main issues:

1. actually mapping out the API response in an interface - its so big and there is so much unnecessary data do I need to put it all in an interface?
2. What do I do if say the client later down the line creates new content types so then the api response coming would be structured slightly differently and at which point the interfaces would be wrong?

All help appreciated, really just need advice down the right way to investigate the solutions.

This is an example of one of the contentful API responses:

```
{
   "sys":{
      "type":"Array"
   },
   "total":2,
   "skip":0,
   "limit":100,
   "items":[
      {
         "metadata":{
            "tags":[
               
            ]
         },
         "sys":{
            "space":{
               "sys":{
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"Space",
                  "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
               }
            },
            "id":"1w9AMDdCqRHRMEfzif3J0V",
            "type":"Entry",
            "createdAt":"2023-06-22T14:17:28.969Z",
            "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T14:17:28.969Z",
            "environment":{
               "sys":{
                  "id":"master",
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"Environment"
               }
            },
            "revision":1,
            "contentType":{
               "sys":{
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"ContentType",
                  "id":"blogPost"
               }
            },
            "locale":"en-US"
         },
         "fields":{
            "title":"Second Test",
            "body":{
               "data":{
                  
               },
               "content":[
                  {
                     "data":{
                        
                     },
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "data":{
                              
                           },
                           "marks":[
                              
                           ],
                           "value":"This is a test.",
                           "nodeType":"text"
                        }
                     ],
                     "nodeType":"paragraph"
                  }
               ],
               "nodeType":"document"
            },
            "tags":[
               {
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Entry",
                     "id":"5vuJaOnrVvh34oAiBt8qgh"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Entry",
                     "id":"6feqnd9taR55ruluGBsp8h"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "metadata":{
            "tags":[
               
            ]
         },
         "sys":{
            "space":{
               "sys":{
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"Space",
                  "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
               }
            },
            "id":"32eWu0P7zXgbxqum5nbdqP",
            "type":"Entry",
            "createdAt":"2023-06-22T14:14:34.053Z",
            "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T14:14:34.053Z",
            "environment":{
               "sys":{
                  "id":"master",
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"Environment"
               }
            },
            "revision":1,
            "contentType":{
               "sys":{
                  "type":"Link",
                  "linkType":"ContentType",
                  "id":"blogPost"
               }
            },
            "locale":"en-US"
         },
         "fields":{
            "title":"Test",
            "body":{
               "data":{
                  
               },
               "content":[
                  {
                     "data":{
                        
                     },
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "data":{
                              
                           },
                           "marks":[
                              
                           ],
                           "value":"This is a test",
                           "nodeType":"text"
                        }
                     ],
                     "nodeType":"heading-1"
                  },
                  {
                     "data":{
                        
                     },
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "data":{
                              
                           },
                           "marks":[
                              
                           ],
                           "value":"",
                           "nodeType":"text"
                        }
                     ],
                     "nodeType":"paragraph"
                  },
                  {
                     "data":{
                        
                     },
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "data":{
                              
                           },
                           "marks":[
                              
                           ],
                           "value":"This is a test",
                           "nodeType":"text"
                        }
                     ],
                     "nodeType":"heading-3"
                  },
                  {
                     "data":{
                        
                     },
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "data":{
                              
                           },
                           "marks":[
                              
                           ],
                           "value":"",
                           "nodeType":"text"
                        }
                     ],
                     "nodeType":"paragraph"
                  },
                  {
                     "data":{
                        
                     },
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "data":{
                              
                           },
                           "marks":[
                              
                           ],
                           "value":"This is a test.",
                           "nodeType":"text"
                        }
                     ],
                     "nodeType":"paragraph"
                  },
                  {
                     "data":{
                        
                     },
                     "content":[
                        {
                           "data":{
                              
                           },
                           "marks":[
                              
                           ],
                           "value":"",
                           "nodeType":"text"
                        }
                     ],
                     "nodeType":"paragraph"
                  }
               ],
               "nodeType":"document"
            },
            "tags":[
               {
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Entry",
                     "id":"63QnQZsSKUUI3TNAvsI19J"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Entry",
                     "id":"1O7OQ1YFLMshW7BwBTL3ER"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "images":[
               {
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Asset",
                     "id":"35LgxsKv96DyW51Uu8DrnM"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Asset",
                     "id":"4bxRR1bBIknnVzRjeqvUIr"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "includes":{
      "Entry":[
         {
            "metadata":{
               "tags":[
                  
               ]
            },
            "sys":{
               "space":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Space",
                     "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
                  }
               },
               "id":"1O7OQ1YFLMshW7BwBTL3ER",
               "type":"Entry",
               "createdAt":"2023-06-22T14:13:23.918Z",
               "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T14:13:23.918Z",
               "environment":{
                  "sys":{
                     "id":"master",
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Environment"
                  }
               },
               "revision":1,
               "contentType":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"ContentType",
                     "id":"countryTag"
                  }
               },
               "locale":"en-US"
            },
            "fields":{
               "countryTag":"usa"
            }
         },
         {
            "metadata":{
               "tags":[
                  
               ]
            },
            "sys":{
               "space":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Space",
                     "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
                  }
               },
               "id":"5vuJaOnrVvh34oAiBt8qgh",
               "type":"Entry",
               "createdAt":"2023-06-22T10:50:36.561Z",
               "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T10:50:36.561Z",
               "environment":{
                  "sys":{
                     "id":"master",
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Environment"
                  }
               },
               "revision":1,
               "contentType":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"ContentType",
                     "id":"countryTag"
                  }
               },
               "locale":"en-US"
            },
            "fields":{
               "countryTag":"australia"
            }
         },
         {
            "metadata":{
               "tags":[
                  
               ]
            },
            "sys":{
               "space":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Space",
                     "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
                  }
               },
               "id":"63QnQZsSKUUI3TNAvsI19J",
               "type":"Entry",
               "createdAt":"2023-06-22T14:13:11.295Z",
               "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T14:13:11.295Z",
               "environment":{
                  "sys":{
                     "id":"master",
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Environment"
                  }
               },
               "revision":1,
               "contentType":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"ContentType",
                     "id":"regionTag"
                  }
               },
               "locale":"en-US"
            },
            "fields":{
               "title":"americas"
            }
         },
         {
            "metadata":{
               "tags":[
                  
               ]
            },
            "sys":{
               "space":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Space",
                     "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
                  }
               },
               "id":"6feqnd9taR55ruluGBsp8h",
               "type":"Entry",
               "createdAt":"2023-06-22T10:41:10.693Z",
               "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T10:41:10.693Z",
               "environment":{
                  "sys":{
                     "id":"master",
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Environment"
                  }
               },
               "revision":1,
               "contentType":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"ContentType",
                     "id":"regionTag"
                  }
               },
               "locale":"en-US"
            },
            "fields":{
               "title":"apac"
            }
         }
      ],
      "Asset":[
         {
            "metadata":{
               "tags":[
                  
               ]
            },
            "sys":{
               "space":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Space",
                     "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
                  }
               },
               "id":"35LgxsKv96DyW51Uu8DrnM",
               "type":"Asset",
               "createdAt":"2023-06-22T14:14:11.979Z",
               "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T14:14:11.979Z",
               "environment":{
                  "sys":{
                     "id":"master",
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Environment"
                  }
               },
               "revision":1,
               "locale":"en-US"
            },
            "fields":{
               "title":"Test1",
               "description":"",
               "file":{
                  "url":"//images.ctfassets.net/rikydtrxnc79/35LgxsKv96DyW51Uu8DrnM/d8a11b6dc57a416a143af10b3569a7e0/pexels-photo-3844788.jpeg",
                  "details":{
                     "size":83381,
                     "image":{
                        "width":500,
                        "height":667
                     }
                  },
                  "fileName":"pexels-photo-3844788.jpeg",
                  "contentType":"image/jpeg"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "metadata":{
               "tags":[
                  
               ]
            },
            "sys":{
               "space":{
                  "sys":{
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Space",
                     "id":"rikydtrxnc79"
                  }
               },
               "id":"4bxRR1bBIknnVzRjeqvUIr",
               "type":"Asset",
               "createdAt":"2023-06-22T14:14:26.979Z",
               "updatedAt":"2023-06-22T14:14:26.979Z",
               "environment":{
                  "sys":{
                     "id":"master",
                     "type":"Link",
                     "linkType":"Environment"
                  }
               },
               "revision":1,
               "locale":"en-US"
            },
            "fields":{
               "title":"Test2",
               "description":"",
               "file":{
                  "url":"//images.ctfassets.net/rikydtrxnc79/4bxRR1bBIknnVzRjeqvUIr/4ffca3cdb4db84b6ee2129cf05f06cdc/premium_photo-1661964088064-dd92eaaa7dcf.jpeg",
                  "details":{
                     "size":46936,
                     "image":{
                        "width":1000,
                        "height":714
                     }
                  },
                  "fileName":"premium_photo-1661964088064-dd92eaaa7dcf.jpeg",
                  "contentType":"image/jpeg"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now the items array and includes array could have different data sets in the objects so this is why I am finding it hard to wrap my head around how to solve the issue of new content types and existing interfaces/schemas not working for them.

I have already mapped it out the response like this but think its excessive?

```
export interface ContentfulApiResponse {
  sys: {
    type: string;
  };
  total: number;
  skip: number;
  limit: number;
  items: [
    {
      metadata: {
        tags: [];
      };
      sys: {
        space: {
          sys: {
            type: string;
            linkType: string;
            id: string;
          };
        };
        id: string;
        type: string;
        createdAt: string;
        updatedAt: string;
        environment: {
          sys: {
            id: string;
            type: string;
            linkType: string;
          };
        };
        revision: number;
        contentType: {
          sys: {
            type: string;
            linkType: string;
            id: string;
          };
        };
        locale: string;
      };
      fields: {
        title: string;
        body: {
          data: {};
          content: [
            {
              data: {};
              content: [
                {
                  data: {};
                  marks: [];
                  value: string;
                  nodeType: string;
                }
              ];
              nodeType: string;
            }
          ];
          nodeType: string;
        };
        tags: [
          {
            sys: {
              type: string;
              linkType: string;
              id: string;
            };
          },
          {
            sys: {
              type: string;
              linkType: string;
              id: string;
            };
          }
        ];
      };
    },
    {
      metadata: {
        tags: [];
      };
      sys: {
        space: {
          sys: {
            type: string;
            linkType: string;
            id: string;
          };
        };
        id: string;
        type: string;
        createdAt: string;
        updatedAt: string;
        environment: {
          sys: {
            id: string;
            type: string;
            linkType: string;
          };
        };
        revision: number;
        contentType: {
          sys: {
            type: string;
            linkType: string;
            id: string;
          };
        };
        locale: string;
      };
      fields: {
        title: string;
        body: {
          data: {};
          content: [
            {
              data: {};
              content: [
                {
                  data: {};
                  marks: [];
                  value: string;
                  nodeType: string;
                }
              ];
              nodeType: string;
            },
            {
              data: {};
              content: [
                {
                  data: {};
                  marks: [];
                  value: string;
                  nodeType: string;
                }
              ];
              nodeType: string;
            },
            {
              data: {};
              content: [
                {
                  data: {};
                  marks: [];
                  value: string;
                  nodeType: string;
                }
              ];
              nodeType: string;
            },
            {
              data: {};
              content: [
                {
                  data: {};
                  marks: [];
                  value: "";
                  nodeType: string;
                }
              ];
              nodeType: string;
            },
            {
              data: {};
              content: [
                {
                  data: {};
                  marks: [];
                  value: string;
                  nodeType: string;
                }
              ];
              nodeType: string;
            },
            {
              data: {};
              content: [
                {
                  data: {};
                  marks: [];
                  value: string;
                  nodeType: string;
                }
              ];
              nodeType: string;
            }
          ];
          nodeType: string;
        };
        tags: [
          {
            sys: {
              type: string;
              linkType: string;
              id: string;
            };
          },
          {
            sys: {
              type: string;
              linkType: string;
              id: string;
            };
          }
        ];
        images: [
          {
            sys: {
              type: string;
              linkType: string;
              id: string;
            };
          },
          {
            sys: {
              type: string;
              linkType: string;
              id: string;
            };
          }
        ];
      };
    }
  ];
  includes: {
    Entry: ContentfulIncludesEntry[];
    Asset: ContentfulIncludesAsset[];
  };
}

interface ContentfulIncludesAsset {
  metadata: {
    tags: [];
  };
  sys: {
    space: {
      sys: {
        type: string;
        linkType: string;
        id: string;
      };
    };
    id: string;
    type: string;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    environment: {
      sys: {
        id: string;
        type: string;
        linkType: string;
      };
    };
    revision: number;
    locale: string;
  };
  fields: {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    file: {
      url: string;
      details: {
        size: number;
        image: {
          width: number;
          height: number;
        };
      };
      fileName: string;
      contentType: string;
    };
  };
}

interface ContentfulIncludesEntry {
  metadata: {
    tags: [];
  };
  sys: {
    space: {
      sys: {
        type: string;
        linkType: string;
        id: string;
      };
    };
    id: string;
    type: string;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    environment: {
      sys: {
        id: string;
        type: string;
        linkType: string;
      };
    };
    revision: number;
    contentType: {
      sys: {
        type: string;
        linkType: string;
        id: string;
      };
    };
    locale: string;
  };
  fields: {
    countryTag?: string;
    regionTag?: string;
  };
}
```

And bear in mind the fields object can change with every content type.

Comment: You only need to define the parts of the interface you're actually using. But this will almost certainly be multiple recursively-defined interfaces that depends on your underlying data. I'm not inclined to try to parse through that stuff on SO: an [mre] should be *minimal*: if that's really the smallest amount of stuff you need to demonstrate the issue then I, for one, probably won't touch it.  If you don't get enough engagement, consider reducing to a smaller version whose solution will help you with the bigger one. If you [edit] to reduce it I'll take another look. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is that you should start by creating a common type for each property name. Sys, Metadata, Tag, Environment, etc, completely ignoring the fact that they'll have circular references that might prevent them from compiling because in this phase you just want to get it all down and understand it. For example:

```js
interface Item {
  metadata?: Metadata;
  sys?: Sys;
  fields?: Fields;
}
```

Another idea is to not even try to strongly type the server response. Instead, accept that the response is `unknown` and then use [zod](https://zod.dev/) to assert the data into the types your code expects. An advantage to this is that run-time assertions will help you find bugs and surprises in ways that unit tests and static type checking simply can't.

However, are you **sure** you need to do any of this yourself? If something like [@bgschiller/contentful-typescript-codegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bgschiller/contentful-typescript-codegen) doesn't help, I'd expect you could find *something* you could use out there?

(Note: I'm not recommending @bgschiller/contentful-typescript-codegen. I'd never heard of it before and only found it by searching for "types/contentful" on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/).)

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic response! yes I have been looking at zod as I have used in a previous company so might go for that approach

Comment: Thanks! Two years ago I would have said something different but, after correspondence with James Coplien about [Why Most Unit Testing is Waste](https://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf), I've accepted that static code checking and unit testing is merely theory, constrained by developers' imaginations, yet the Mark Twain quote "Truth is stranger than fiction, but it is because Fiction is obliged to stick to possibilities; Truth isn't." directly applies to code development.